# How to update a global variable inside `where` clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, where-clause, extension-methods

I want to filter a list using `LINQ` with `Where` extension method. But apart from filtering I also want to update a global variable inside `Where`. However I cannot do it. Consider this example:

```
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

bool flag = false;
var newList = list.Where(item =>
{
    flag = true;
    return item == "2";
});

// Here I expect flag = true, but in fact it's false
Console.Write(flag);
```

As you can see I set `flag = true`, still the value `flag == false` after execution. It does not make sense to me. Can you explain what is going on under the hood and why `flag` is not changed. Also is there a way to change global variables inside `LINQ` at all?

Comment: The Q in LINQ stands for QUERY (read) and not intended to set values.  A WHERE doesn't return values either.

Comment: What's your actual requirement?

Comment: You want to return a new list based on your existing list, where what?

Comment: Your method works, but the predicate is never executed because you don't enumerate the `newList`. But I would also recommend not having side effects in the where predicate.

Comment: `Where` filters. So if you want an item that `== 2` you can do that. You can also see if there is any results or not, and "tell" if it was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq queries are lazy, so until you enumerate newList you will not see a change, because your where has not been executed.

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

bool flag = false;
var newList = list.Where(item =>
{
    flag = true;
    return item == "2";
});

Console.WriteLine(flag); // Flag is still false.

foreach (var item in newList) {
  // It doesn't matter what we do here, just that we enumerate the list.
}

Console.Write(flag); // Flag is now true.
```

The foreach causes the where to execute and sets your flag.

I would really advise against using the where predicate to create a side effect, by the way, but this is how you'd do it.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to actually execute the code that sets the `flag`:

```
var newList = list.Where(item =>
{
    flag = true;
    return item == "2";
}).ToArray();
```

The predicate that you pass to the `Where` method is not evaluated until the list is actually enumerated.